# Inject Row into Query Results with T_SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I currently have an issue where I am needing to report the values of a few areas of sales within a database.  The second `SELECT of this is giving me what I want to know, and the first part also gives me what I want to know.  But I am curious if it is possible to some how make the result of the first query, appear as a row in the second...

If I just add `@something` to the second `SELECT` then it appears as a column and gives results like:

```
TOTAL     | CATEGORY    | (NO COLUMN NAME)
-------------------------------------------
70000.11  | CATEGORY 1  | 118500
31200.11  | CATEGORY 2  | 118500
51114.11  | CATEGORY 3  | 118500
2215.11   | CATEGORY 4  | 118500
54321.11  | CATEGORY 5  | 118500
```

But, essentially I would like to figure out if its possible to inject it into the results so it appears like:

```
TOTAL     | CATEGORY  
----------------------
70000.11  | CATEGORY 1
31200.11  | CATEGORY 2
51114.11  | CATEGORY 3
2215.11   | CATEGORY 4
54321.11  | CATEGORY 5
118500.00 | SOMETHING
```

I modified the column names and such so I hope it isn't confusing.  I thought about attempting to generate a temporary table, pull the values into it and just do a INSERT INTO @myTable on it?  I'm a bit familiar with that, but not sure if its the most efficient way.

Ultimately, this will move into a stored procedure.

```
USE Database1
GO
DECLARE @something NUMERIC
SET @something = (SELECT 
        ABS(SUM(ENTRY_AMT)) AS 'Total'

    FROM 
        Invoices AS gl

        LEFT JOIN Orders AS iod ON gl.ORDER_NO = iod.ORDER_NO AND gl.LINE_NO = iod.LINE_NO AND gl.APPEND = iod.APPEND

    WHERE 
        gl.YR = 13 
        AND gl.PERIOD = 1 
        AND ENTRY_SRC = 'revenue' 
        AND iod.CATEGORY_DESC IN ('GENERAL', 'OTHER', 'RANDOM') 

        AND (gl.GL_ACCOUNT_NO BETWEEN 7100000000 AND 7100999999)
        AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RS'
        AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RA'
)


(SELECT 
    ABS(SUM(ENTRY_AMT)) AS 'Total', 
    CATEGORY_DESC AS 'Category'


FROM 
    Invoices AS gl

    LEFT JOIN Orders AS iod ON gl.ORDER_NO = iod.ORDER_NO AND gl.LINE_NO = iod.LINE_NO AND gl.APPEND = iod.APPEND

WHERE 
        gl.YR = 13 
    AND gl.PERIOD = 1 
    AND ENTRY_SRC = 'revenue' 
    AND iod.CATEGORY_DESC NOT IN ('GENERAL', 'OTHER', 'RANDOM') 

    AND (gl.GL_ACCOUNT_NO BETWEEN 7100000000 AND 7100999999)
    AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RS'
    AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RA'


GROUP BY CATEGORY_DESC
)
```

Comment: Union the results would be one way; but there's a concept called analytics which provide grouping sets and cubes which will do what you want as well and generally perform better. like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    USE Database1
    GO
(SELECT 
                ABS(SUM(ENTRY_AMT)) AS 'Total',
'All' as Category

        FROM 
            Invoices AS gl

            LEFT JOIN Orders AS iod ON gl.ORDER_NO = iod.ORDER_NO AND gl.LINE_NO = iod.LINE_NO AND gl.APPEND = iod.APPEND

        WHERE 
            gl.YR = 13 
            AND gl.PERIOD = 1 
            AND ENTRY_SRC = 'revenue' 
            AND iod.CATEGORY_DESC IN ('GENERAL', 'OTHER', 'RANDOM') 

            AND (gl.GL_ACCOUNT_NO BETWEEN 7100000000 AND 7100999999)
            AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RS'
            AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RA'
    )
    UNION

    (SELECT 
        ABS(SUM(ENTRY_AMT)) AS 'Total', 
        CATEGORY_DESC AS 'Category'


    FROM 
        Invoices AS gl

        LEFT JOIN Orders AS iod ON gl.ORDER_NO = iod.ORDER_NO AND gl.LINE_NO = iod.LINE_NO AND gl.APPEND = iod.APPEND

    WHERE 
            gl.YR = 13 
        AND gl.PERIOD = 1 
        AND ENTRY_SRC = 'revenue' 
        AND iod.CATEGORY_DESC NOT IN ('GENERAL', 'OTHER', 'RANDOM') 

        AND (gl.GL_ACCOUNT_NO BETWEEN 7100000000 AND 7100999999)
        AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RS'
        AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RA'


    GROUP BY CATEGORY_DESC
```

### )

OR and I think this is easier...

```
    (SELECT 
        ABS(SUM(ENTRY_AMT)) AS 'Total', 
        CATEGORY_DESC AS 'Category'


    FROM 
        Invoices AS gl

        LEFT JOIN Orders AS iod ON gl.ORDER_NO = iod.ORDER_NO AND gl.LINE_NO = iod.LINE_NO AND gl.APPEND = iod.APPEND

    WHERE 
            gl.YR = 13 
        AND gl.PERIOD = 1 
        AND ENTRY_SRC = 'revenue' 
        AND iod.CATEGORY_DESC NOT IN ('GENERAL', 'OTHER', 'RANDOM') 

        AND (gl.GL_ACCOUNT_NO BETWEEN 7100000000 AND 7100999999)
        AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RS'
        AND gl.ITEM_NO NOT LIKE '%RA'


    GROUP BY Grouping sets ((CATEGORY_DESC),())
    )
```

Comment: Wonderful.  This was a great experience for me to understand how UNION and UNION ALL work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that @something isn't a total of the rest or something similar, in which case you want to look into grouping sets and cubes like @xQbert suggested.  If it isn't then try this.

```
<-- Your Query Here -->
UNION ALL -- Make sure it's a UNION ALL not a UNION or you will lose duplicate rows.
SELECT @Something AS Total, 'Something' AS Category
```

Comment: Thank you Kenneth!  I appreciate the reference to UNION ALL.